# Typescript external function for type check and compilation error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

**Fact:**
I'm using TS v. 2.3.4. I've created a function that checks weather a veriable is defined (it takes `variable` as parameter and returns `'undefined' !== typeof variable`). A peace of cake.

```
export function IsDefined(variable: any): boolean {
    return 'undefined' !== typeof variable;
}
```

**Problem:** Below code produces a warning on 2. line. The waring says *Object is possibly undefined*.

```
if (IsDefined(myVar)) {
    myVar.mockProperty = "asdf"; //Object (myVar, obviously) is possibly undefined
}
```

**Question:** Is there any way to tell TS compiler that `IsDefined()` method checks variable against undefined value, so it doesn't warn with fake info? Are there any other methods to work this around?

**Workarounds I know and I'm NOT willing to use, since they makes the code unclean:**

- `(<myType>myVar).mockProperty = "asdf";`
- `if ("undefined" !== typeof myVar) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a type guard here. Change the definition of `IsDefined`:

```
export function IsDefined(variable: any): variable is {} {
    return 'undefined' !== typeof variable;
}
```

and now the compiler will know that anything which returns `true` from `IsDefined` is an object and not `undefined`.

Comment: Wow, nice feature. I must've read the docs in hurry ;) Thanks!